# vaadin grid shows no object data (jpa)

Tags: java, object, jpa, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I've a problem with my vaadin grid. I can easily set a newly created List of Objects like here:

```
private Grid<Objective> test = new Grid<>(Objective.class);

List<Objective> people = Arrays.asList(
        new Objective("Nicolaus Copernicus","lol", 1),
        new Objective("Santaklaus Copernicus","qwr", 2),
        new Objective("Omarklaus Copernicus","asdf", 3));

test.setColumns("name", "difficulty");
test.setItems(sampleData);
```

This looks like pic1 and it works. 
[image: pic1]

But if i wanna display my List of Objectives (saved via JPA in relationship to a Patient Model) it doesnt work (shows nothing). The size() is that i can "select" the objective bc lazy loading is standard. What can i do? Tested out so many things but nothing works.

```
@Override
public void fillObjectiveList(ObjectiveList objectiveList) {
    test.setColumns("name", "difficulty");

    List<Objective> realData = objectiveList.getObjectives();
    realData.size();
    test.setItems(sampleData);

}
```

ObjectiveList Class:

```
@Entity
public class ObjectiveList {

   ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy= "objList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Objective> objectives = new ArrayList<Objective>();

  ....

    public List<Objective> getObjectives() {
        return objectives;
    }
```

This works fine, so i can grab the attributes from the list.

```
realData.get(0).getName();
```

Every data is connected via the patient with oneToOne or ManyToOne etc.
Patient oneToOne ObjectiveList oneToMany Objective

Can someone help me? I didnt paste the hole code, bc its quite big. If you need more code, just say which part. Thanks!

edit1:

a difference i noticed is the bracket if i sysout the list:
manualy created list

> [ch.bfh.btx8081.w2017.blue.sophobia.model.Objective@6ad2b61e,
>   ch.bfh.btx8081.w2017.blue.sophobia.model.Objective@66ce6ca4,
>   ch.bfh.btx8081.w2017.blue.sophobia.model.Objective@3d577486]

jpa created list

> {[ch.bfh.btx8081.w2017.blue.sophobia.model.Objective@214a78ec,
>   ch.bfh.btx8081.w2017.blue.sophobia.model.Objective@66e93870]}

Comment: In `fillObjectiveList` do you have a typo? You call test.setItems with parameter `sampleData` but should be calling with variable `realData`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it's solved. i had to add 'fetch=FetchType.EAGER' to my objectiveList. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grid.addColumn(Objective::getName).setCaption("Name");
grid.addColumn(Objective::getDifficulty).setCaption("Difficulty");
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it's solved. i had to add 'fetch=FetchType.EAGER' to my objectiveList. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved. I had to add 'fetch=FetchType.EAGER' to my objectiveList.